# Conditional SQL Statement DB2 Based on columns

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm not sure if this is possible, I have a java program which runs a given query (JDBC) and outputs the results into an excel file. The connection/db info is IBM as400, V7R1M0.

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
 ====================    =================================
 |      TABLE1      |    |             TABLE2            | 
 ====================    =================================   
 | Company |  CODE  |    |  ID   | CODE1 | CODE2 | CODE3 |
 --------------------    --------------------------------
 |   001   |   E1   |    |   1   |  10   |  18   |   21  |
 |   005   |   E3   |    |   2   |  14   |  19   |   23  |
 |   009   |   E1   |    |   3   |  17   |  20   |   25  |   
 |   015   |   E2   |    |   4   |   5   |  11   |   15  |
 ====================    =================================
```

My expected results will be like:

```
==============================
           RESULTS
==============================
|  Company  |  CODE  | CODE3 |
------------------------------
|    005    |   E3   |   21  |
==============================
```

Note(s):

> - TABLE1.CODE will tell us what column from TABLE2 to choose from.
> - TABLE1.COMPANY's CODE changes randomly
> - I only need one row from TABLE2, assume ID = 1 always.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I read that IBM AS400 doesn't allow `IF ... ELSE.`

My idea is kinda-of like (Pseudocode):

```
SET Value = SELECT CODE FROM TABLE1 WHERE Company ='005'
IF Value = 'E1'
   SELECT CODE1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 1;
ELSE IF Value = 'E2'
   SELECT CODE2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 1;
...
```

**EDIT**

I know I can do this in Java. but I don't want to change it. Can it be done from SQL statement?

Comment: `IF ... ELSE` is part of the SQL Persistent Stored Modules (SQL/PSM)  standards used when created stored procedures and functions.  `CASE` is provides similar functionality within an standard SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express this as a SQL query:

```
select t1.company, t1.code,
       (case when t1.code = 'E1' then t2.code1
             when t1.code = 'E2' then t2.code2
             when t1.code = 'E3' then t2.code3
        end) as t1_code
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.Company, a.Code, 
    case a.Code
        when 'E1' then b.Code1
        when 'E2' then b.Code2
        when 'E3' then b.Code3
      end 
From table1 a
   join table2 b on b.Id = 1
Where c.Company ='005'
```